# Toggle raphael object's colour on click

Tags: javascript, html, string, toggle, raphael

I've created a rectangle using raphael.js.
`var rect = paper.rect(x,y,width,height);` Assume that x, y, width and height has some values.
I'd like to add in a mouse click handler that'll toggle the rectangle's "fill" colour on click.

Other than using 'if...else...', how can I toggle the colour between 'red' and 'green' on click??
something that'll replace "if...else..." in the following function:

```
var colour = 'red';
rect.node.onclick = function(){
    if (colour == 'red') colour = 'green';
    else if (colour == 'green') colour = 'red';
    this.setAttribute("fill",colour);
}
```

UPDATE:

```
var fill = 'red';
rect.node.onclick = function(){
    fill  = (fill == 'red') ? 'green': 'red';
    console.log(fill);
    this.setAttribute("fill", fill);
}
```

I can now see my fill toggling between red and green on my console. but it doesn't change the actual rectangle's colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
rect.node.onclick = function(){
    var currentColor = this.getAttribute('fill');
    var targetColor = (currentColor === 'red') ? 'green' : 'red';
    this.setAttribute("fill", targetColor);
}
```

That should work even if no fill color is set.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like if you are using Raphael, it makes sense to use Raphs methods, and avoid things like Raphaels internal accessors like node(). So you could rewrite it as

```
rect.click( function() {
    this.attr({ fill: this.attr('fill') == 'green' ? 'red' : 'green' }); 
});
```